# how to make smooth transition when using image src

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to display list of images using the img src in HTML.
But the way it displayed when downloading doesn't look too good.
I was wondering if there's any way to make the transition before
the download is complete.

TIA.

Comment: Transition of what before download is complete? Please edit your post with more details and what you have tried.

Comment: No, you should preload the images and start the transition when the download is finished to achieve a smooth effect.

Comment: There's no way to create a smooth effect while the image is downloading, because the rendering is done top-to-bottom, and you can't change how it's done. You can, though, predownload the image, then create an effect while **showing** it.